# RegExp to match values in list of key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of key-value pairs like this:

```
key1 val1
key2 val2
key3 val3
```

I want a regular expression to match just the values. For example:

```
['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
```

I have not found a way to do this without negative lookbehind, which is not available in javascript.

Comment: Is the list of key-value pairs already an array?

Comment: To continue what @axelduch said, or is it already an actual object? like `var obj = { 'key1': 'val1' };` ?

Comment: @axelduch no it's plain text in a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a regex like: `/.*\ (.*)/g` | Tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/nZ2zE3/1)

A full working loop:

```
var str = "key1 val1\nkey2 val2\nkey3 val3";
regex = /.*\ (.*)/g;
values = [];
while ((result = regex.exec(str))) {
   values.push(result[1]);
}
```

---

Also I personally use tools like [this](https://regex101.com/#pcre) for regex testing, it is very handy when you are starting out.

Comment: Thanks for the tool; it's better than what I was using. However, this RE doesn't work exactly the way I want because calling .match(/.*\ (.*)/gmi) on it will return ["key1 val1", "key2 val2", "key3 val3"]

Comment: You can also use `/.*? (.*?)(?:\s|$)/gm` to catch cases where there isn't a `\n` character - https://regex101.com/r/kS0wN2/1

Comment: @sebastianForsberg Didn't think of that. I was trying to do a global match and narrow down with a loop. This is much cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: @sebastianForsberg Just implemented. Works great! :D

Answer (score 1):

If there is a single space in between key and values you can just split by space char

```
var str = 'key1 val1';
var data = str.split(' ');
var key = data[0];
var value = data[1];
```

Now, if your values may contain spaces

```
var str = 'key1 val1';
var data = str.split(' ');
var key = data.shift();
var value = data.join(' ');
```

Comment: I already have something like that. I was just looking for a simpler way to do it with a single .match() for the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var str = "key1 val1\nkey2 val2\nkey3 val3";

var result = str.split(/\n/).map(function(item) {
  return /.* (.*)/.exec(item)[1];
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yLk7hs86/2/